# Count number of non-numeric characters in a string

Tags: r, string, count, tidyverse

How do I count the number of non-numeric characters in a string with both numeric and non-numeric characters in R

for example:

```
c("ab34","f354","q64423","abf3")
```

I would like the output to be:

```
c(2,1,1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) gsub** Replace digits with the empty string and count what is left.  No packages are used.

```
x <- c("ab34","f354","q64423","abf3")
nchar(gsub("\\d", "", x))
## [1] 2 1 1 3
```

**2) gregexpr** Another possibility is to use gregexpr and lengths to count the non-numerics. We append a non-numeric to each component so that the value can never be zero (as gregexpr returns NA in that case) and then subtract 1 in the end.

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\D", paste0(x, "X"))) - 1
## [1] 2 1 1 3
```

**3) strsplit / %in%** split the strings into individual characters and sum the number that are not in 0:9

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) sum(!x %in% 0:9))
[1] 2 1 1 3
```

**4) trimws** In the example in the question the numerics are always at the end (or even if they were at the beginning) we can trim them off and then count what is left.

```
nchar(trimws(x, white = "\\d"))
## [1] 2 1 1 3
```

**5) regexpr** If the digits are always at the end then we can use regexpr to find the position of the first one.  We append a 0 to ensure that there is at least one digit and subtract 1 at the end.

```
c(regexpr("\\d", paste0(x, 0)) - 1)
## [1] 2 1 1 3
```